# Creating, shuffling, and dealing a deck of cards using classes in c++

Tags: c++

Ok, so I'm working on a final project for a computer science class, and I'm just having trouble grasping how to move forward with the assignment.

The criteria provided are:
Create a standard deck of 52 playing cards and list those cards on the screen. Pause after the unshuffled deck is displayed.

"Shuffle" the deck and list the shuffled deck on the screen.  random_shuffle from  will work on a vector of Cards

Sort (by rank) and evaluate the first 5 cards of the deck as a 'hand'.  Print the unsorted, then the sorted hand.

Then we have to check for things like pairs, three of a kind, full house, straights, flushes, etc. (Which I'm pretty confident I can handle)

The professor gave us this code as an idea for a card class to go off of:

```
#ifndef CARD_H

#define CARD_H


class Card
{
public:
    Card();

    // set and get the rank, 2=2, 3=3, ... 10=10, 11=J, 12=Q, 13=K, 14=A
    void setRank(int r);
    int getRank();

    // set and get the suit, 1=Spades, 2=Hearts, ...
    void setSuit(int r);
    int getSuit();

    // for debugging, print the suit and rand as integers
    void print();

    // return the rank and suit as a 'nice' looking string
    void toString();

protected:
private:
    int myRank;
    int mySuit;
};
#endif // CARD_H
```

Reading around, it seems like I may need to make deck and hand classes too, but because their goals and restrictions always seemed to be different, I'm just not sure how to really proceed with this. I'm pretty confident that once I figure out which classes I'll need and how to make them play nice together and initiate properly, I'll be able to piece it all together and finish the rest rather easily.

Could anyone point me in the right direction on this?

Comment: you dont need a Deck or Hand class - just a vector of 52 Cards

Comment: I'd say it's not necessary but will surely make it more concise and maintainable. `Deck` of `Cards` with an `enum` for `Suits`; could have a `Shuffler` too.

Comment: And take some time to learn about [`std::vector<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). Also, [`std::shuffle`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) in conjunction with [`<random>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) will make short-work of the actual shuffle. The example linked for `std::shuffle` shuffles a vector of `int`. Figure out a way to make that a vector of `Card` and you're on your way.

Comment: I would pack the cards into a single `char` each: `class card{unsigned char rank : 6; unsigned char suit : 2;/*members...*/};` Also, using an unscoped `enum` to get all the constants you want in-class is a good idea.

Comment: Anyway, I wouldn't add any additional classes, just use free function algorithms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you don't need a class for a Deck or for a Hand. There might be cases where you might need those as a separate class, but in this particular case, just a vector of cards will work (it actually gives you a hint about the fact that you need to use a vector for `random_shuffle`. The hand is represented by 5 consecutive elements of this vector.

Although not directly related to your question, I would like to mention an article called [The Danger of Naïveté](http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-danger-of-naivete/) where the shuffling problem is analysed. It might help you create a real shffling, with an uniform distribution.